# CRT Doesn't print line number of memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, crt

I've got the code below, which I think, based on [Finding Memory Leaks Using the CRT Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx), should print out the line number of a memory leak.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <iostream>


void derp()
{
    int* q = new int;

}

int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    derp();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I get the following:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{75} normal block at 0x0067E930, 4 bytes long.
 Data: <    > CD CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.
```

Based on Microsoft's documentation, I'd expect to see a print-out of the line where the leaky memory was allocated, but I don't.

What have I done wrong? I'm using VS2015.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3202520/4009370

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [MSDN topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx):

> These techniques work for memory allocated using the standard CRT
>   malloc function. If your program allocates memory using the C++ new
>   operator, however, you may only see the file and line number where the
>   implementation of global operator new calls _malloc_dbg in the
>   memory-leak report. Because that behavior is not very useful, you can
>   change it to report the line that made the allocation by using a macro
>   that looks like this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #define DBG_NEW new ( _NORMAL_BLOCK , __FILE__ , __LINE__ )
    // Replace _NORMAL_BLOCK with _CLIENT_BLOCK if you want the
    // allocations to be of _CLIENT_BLOCK type
#else
    #define DBG_NEW new
#endif
```

And then replace the `new` in your code with `DBG_NEW`. I tested it and it works correctly with your code.

---

Actually, replacing the `new` with `DBG_NEW` everywhere in the code is too tedious task, so possibly your could use this macro:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
     #define new new( _NORMAL_BLOCK , __FILE__ , __LINE__ )
#else
     #define new new
#endif
```

I tested this method and it works too.

Comment: good one.. but their offer is outdated, we can overload new https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/calvin_hsia/2009/01/19/overload-operator-new-to-detect-memory-leaks/

Answer (score 2):

Check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3203429/4009370). You want to use overloaded `new` operator with the additional parameters as specified in the solution there in order to get that information.

In this case, change your line

```
int* q = new int;
```

to

```
int* q = new (_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__) int;
```

and you should see the leaks.

Answer (score 0):

It should have been answered somewhere already.

> "These techniques work for memory allocated using the  standard CRT
>   malloc function. If your program allocates memory using the C++ new
>   operator, however, you need to redefine new if you want to see the
>   file and line numbers in the memory-leak report."

In result you would have line of your new operator definition. you may use the trick that new can accept extra parameters and some of them can be defaulted to value of macrodefinitions, such like `__LINE__` and `__FILE__`